# Return 64 bits by sum of 32 bits variable

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm working with assebmly IA32, I'm having some doubts working with this since I have no experience.
I want to do somethin like this:
A + B (both 32 bits).
The function retorns a value of 64 bits.
Please do not make it very difficult to me to understand this.
Thank you!!!!

Comment: `movl a, %eax; addl b, %eax; subb %edx, %edx; negl %edx; ret;` should do for `unsigned`. Signed is left as an exercise to you.

Comment: Show your attempt first. We'll help you fix it in case it doesn't work properly.

Comment: done, sorry about that :D

Answer (score 0):

I did that (I really don't think it is correct), sorry comments are in Portuguese
.section .data

```
.global op1
.global op2
```

.section .text

```
.global soma

soma:

    movl op1, %eax  # move op1 para o registo %eax

    movl op2, %ebx # move op2 para o registo %ebx

    addl %ebx, %eax # adiciona %ebx a %eax e guarda em %eax

    movl $0, %edx;

    # jump if carry
    jc output_com_carry

    jmp fim

output_com_carry:

    movl $1, %edx

    jmp fim

fim:


ret
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but you could simplify the code for clarity. Jump if there's **no carry** over the instruction `movl $1, %edx`. Also jumping to a label that immediately follows is kind of redundant. And also you don't have to put *op2* in the EBX register. You can directly add *op2* to the EAX register.